# How is the Tf-Idf value calculated with analyzer ='char'?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm having a problem in understanding how we got the Tf-Idf in the following program:

I have tried calculating the value of `a` in the document 2 (`'And_this_is_the_third_one.'`) using the concept given on the [site](https://www.kaggle.com/divsinha/sentiment-analysis-countvectorizer-tf-idf), but my value of 'a' using the above concept is

> 1/26*log(4/1)
>
> ((count of occurrence of 'a' character)/(no of characters in the given
>   document)*log( # Docs/ # Docs in which given character
>   occurred))
>
> = 0.023156

But output is returned as 0.2203 as can be seen in the output.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ['This_is_the_first_document.', 'This_document_is_the_second_document.', 'And_this_is_the_third_one.', 'Is_this_the_first_document?', ]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.0, analyzer="char")
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
m = X.todense()
print(m)
```

I expected the output to be 0.023156 using the concept explained above.

The output is:

```
['.', '?', '_', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'u']


{'t': 15, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 's': 14, '_': 2, 'e': 6, 'f': 7, 'r': 13, 'd': 5, 'o': 12, 'c': 4, 'u': 16, 'm': 10, 'n': 11, '.': 0, 'a': 3, '?': 1}


[[0.14540332 0.         0.47550697 0.         0.14540332 0.11887674
  0.23775349 0.17960203 0.23775349 0.35663023 0.14540332 0.11887674
  0.11887674 0.14540332 0.35663023 0.47550697 0.14540332]


 [0.10814145 0.         0.44206359 0.         0.32442434 0.26523816
  0.35365088 0.         0.17682544 0.17682544 0.21628289 0.26523816
  0.26523816 0.         0.26523816 0.35365088 0.21628289]


 [0.14061506 0.         0.57481012 0.22030066 0.         0.22992405
  0.22992405 0.         0.34488607 0.34488607 0.         0.22992405
  0.11496202 0.14061506 0.22992405 0.34488607 0.        ]


 [0.         0.2243785  0.46836004 0.         0.14321789 0.11709001
  0.23418002 0.17690259 0.23418002 0.35127003 0.14321789 0.11709001
  0.11709001 0.14321789 0.35127003 0.46836004 0.14321789]]
```

Comment: What is *"the con"* (in this context)?

Comment: "the con" you mean "the concept"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TfidfVectorizer()` has smoothing added to the document counts and `l2` normalization been applied on top tf-idf vector, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting).

> (count of occurrence of the character)/(no of characters in the given
>   document) *
>   log (1 + # Docs / 1 + # Docs in which the given character is present) +1 )

This Normalization is `l2` by default, but you can change or remove this step by using the parameter `norm`. Similarly, smoothing can be

To understand how does the exact score is computed, I am going to fit a `CountVectorizer()` to know the counts of each character in every document.

```
countVectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char')
tf = countVectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
tf_df = pd.DataFrame(tf.toarray(),
                     columns= countVectorizer.get_feature_names())
tf_df

#output:
   .  ?  _  a  c  d  e  f  h  i  m  n  o  r  s  t  u
0  1  0  4  0  1  1  2  1  2  3  1  1  1  1  3  4  1
1  1  0  5  0  3  3  4  0  2  2  2  3  3  0  3  4  2
2  1  0  5  1  0  2  2  0  3  3  0  2  1  1  2  3  0
3  0  1  4  0  1  1  2  1  2  3  1  1  1  1  3  4  1
```

Let us apply the tf-idf weighting based on sklearn implementation now for the second document now!

```
v=[]
doc_id = 2
# number of documents in the corpus + smoothing
n_d = 1+ tf_df.shape[0]

for char in tf_df.columns:
    # calculate tf - count of this char in the doc / total number chars in the doc
    tf = tf_df.loc[doc_id,char]/tf_df.loc[doc_id,:].sum()

    # number of documents containing this char with smoothing 
    df_d_t = 1+ sum(tf_df.loc[:,char]>0)
    # now calculate the idf with smoothing 
    idf = (np.log (n_d/df_d_t) + 1 )

    # calculate the score now
    v.append (tf*idf)

from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

# normalize the vector with l2 norm and create a dataframe with feature_names

pd.DataFrame(normalize([v], norm='l2'), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())

#output:

       .    ?        _         a    c         d         e    f         h        i    m         n         o         r         s         t    u  
 0.140615  0.0  0.57481  0.220301  0.0  0.229924  0.229924  0.0  0.344886   0.344886  0.0  0.229924  0.114962  0.140615  0.229924  0.344886  0.0
```

you could find that the score for char `a` matches with the `TfidfVectorizer()` output!!!

Comment: Thank you very much @Al_Learning, it's very clear now

Comment: Please, tell us what the smoothing Similarly, can be

Comment: Adding 1 in both steps is the smoothening aspect. If you find it confusing still please ask a new question with more details on it.