# PySpark vs sklearn TFIDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

I'm new to PySpark. I was playing around with the tfidf. Just wanted to check if they are giving same results. But they are not same. Here's what I did.

```
# create the PySpark dataframe
sentenceData = sqlContext.createDataFrame((
  (0.0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
  (0.0, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
  (1.0, "Logistic regression models are neat")
)).toDF("label", "sentence")

# tokenize
tokenizer = Tokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)

# vectorize
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(inputCol='words', outputCol='vectorizer').fit(wordsData)
wordsData = vectorizer.transform(wordsData)

# calculate scores
idf = IDF(inputCol="vectorizer", outputCol="tfidf_features")
idf_model = idf.fit(wordsData)
wordsData = idf_model.transform(wordsData)

# dense the current response variable
def to_dense(in_vec):
    return DenseVector(in_vec.toArray())
to_dense_udf = udf(lambda x: to_dense(x), VectorUDT())

# create dense vector
wordsData = wordsData.withColumn("tfidf_features_dense", to_dense_udf('tfidf_features'))
```

I converted the PySpark df to pandas

```
wordsData_pandas = wordsData.toPandas()
```

and, then just calculating using sklearn's tfidf as following

```
def dummy_fun(doc):
    return doc

# create sklearn tfidf
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(
    analyzer='word',
    tokenizer=dummy_fun,
    preprocessor=dummy_fun,
    token_pattern=None)  

# transform and get idf scores
feature_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(wordsData_pandas.words)

# create sklearn dtm matrix
sklearn_tfifdf = pd.DataFrame(feature_matrix.toarray(), columns=tfidf.get_feature_names())

# create PySpark dtm matrix
spark_tfidf = pd.DataFrame([np.array(i) for i in wordsData_pandas.tfidf_features_dense], columns=vectorizer.vocabulary)
```

But unfortunately, I'm getting this for PySpark

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">  <thead>    <tr style="text-align: right;">      <th></th>      <th>i</th>      <th>are</th>      <th>logistic</th>      <th>case</th>      <th>spark</th>      <th>hi</th>      <th>about</th>      <th>neat</th>      <th>could</th>      <th>regression</th>      <th>wish</th>      <th>use</th>      <th>heard</th>      <th>classes</th>      <th>java</th>      <th>models</th>    </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>    <tr>      <th>0</th>      <td>0.287682</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>1</th>      <td>0.287682</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.000000</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>2</th>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.693147</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.693147</td>    </tr>  </tbody></table>
```

and this for sklearn,

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">  <thead>    <tr style="text-align: right;">      <th></th>      <th>i</th>      <th>are</th>      <th>logistic</th>      <th>case</th>      <th>spark</th>      <th>hi</th>      <th>about</th>      <th>neat</th>      <th>could</th>      <th>regression</th>      <th>wish</th>      <th>use</th>      <th>heard</th>      <th>classes</th>      <th>java</th>      <th>models</th>    </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>    <tr>      <th>0</th>      <td>0.355432</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.467351</td>      <td>0.467351</td>      <td>0.467351</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.467351</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>1</th>      <td>0.296520</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.389888</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.389888</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.389888</td>      <td>0.389888</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.389888</td>      <td>0.389888</td>      <td>0.000000</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>2</th>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.447214</td>      <td>0.447214</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.447214</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.447214</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.000000</td>      <td>0.447214</td>    </tr>  </tbody></table>
```

I did try out the `use_idf`, `smooth_idf` paramters. But none seem to make both same. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because the IDFs are calculated a little differently between the two.

From sklearn's [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction):

[image]

Compare to pyspark's [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/ml-features.html#tf-idf):

[image]

Besides the addition of the 1 in the IDF the sklearn TF-IDF uses the l2 norm which pyspark doesn't

```
TfidfTransformer(norm='l2', use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False)
```

Comment: @HakunaMaData, we can get the same result with sklearn, if we set norm to None in Sklearn.

Answer (score 9):

Both Python and Pyspark implementation of tfidf scores are the same. Refer the same Sklearn document but on following line,

[image]

The key difference between them is that Sklearn uses `l2` norm by default, which is not the case with Pyspark. If we set the norm to None, we will get the same result in sklearn as well.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

corpus = ["I heard about Spark","I wish Java could use case classes","Logistic regression models are neat"]
corpus = [sent.lower().split() for sent in corpus]

def dummy_fun(doc):
    return doc

tfidfVectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(norm=None,analyzer='word',
                                tokenizer=dummy_fun,preprocessor=dummy_fun,token_pattern=None)

tf=tfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
tf_df=pd.DataFrame(tf.toarray(),columns= tfidfVectorizer.get_feature_names())
tf_df
```

[image]

Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920770/how-is-the-tf-idf-value-calculated-with-analyzer-char) to understand how norm works with tf-idf vectorizer.