# What is the math behind TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to understand the math behind the `TfidfVectorizer`. I used [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-feature-engineering-using-tf-idf-e8b9d00e7e76) tutorial, but my code is a little bit changed:

what also says at the end that `The values differ slightly because sklearn uses a smoothed version idf and various other little optimizations.`

I want to be able to use `TfidfVectorizer` but also calculate the same simple sample by my hand.

Here is my whole code:
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

```
def main():
    documentA = 'the man went out for a walk'
    documentB = 'the children sat around the fire'
    corpus = [documentA, documentB]
    bagOfWordsA = documentA.split(' ')
    bagOfWordsB = documentB.split(' ')

    uniqueWords = set(bagOfWordsA).union(set(bagOfWordsB))

    print('----------- compare word count -------------------')
    numOfWordsA = dict.fromkeys(uniqueWords, 0)
    for word in bagOfWordsA:
        numOfWordsA[word] += 1
    numOfWordsB = dict.fromkeys(uniqueWords, 0)
    for word in bagOfWordsB:
        numOfWordsB[word] += 1

    tfA = computeTF(numOfWordsA, bagOfWordsA)
    tfB = computeTF(numOfWordsB, bagOfWordsB)
    print(pd.DataFrame([tfA, tfB]))

    CV = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w*\\b')
    cv_ft = CV.fit_transform(corpus)

    tt = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False, norm='l1')
    t = tt.fit_transform(cv_ft)
    print(pd.DataFrame(t.todense().tolist(), columns=CV.get_feature_names()))

    print('----------- compare idf -------------------')
    idfs = computeIDF([numOfWordsA, numOfWordsB])
    print(pd.DataFrame([idfs]))

    tfidfA = computeTFIDF(tfA, idfs)
    tfidfB = computeTFIDF(tfB, idfs)
    print(pd.DataFrame([tfidfA, tfidfB]))

    ttf = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True, smooth_idf=False, norm=None)
    f = ttf.fit_transform(cv_ft)
    print(pd.DataFrame(f.todense().tolist(), columns=CV.get_feature_names()))

    print('----------- TfidfVectorizer -------------------')
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False, use_idf=True, stop_words=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w*\\b', norm=None)
    vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform([documentA, documentB])
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    print(pd.DataFrame(vectors.todense().tolist(), columns=feature_names))


def computeTF(wordDict, bagOfWords):
    tfDict = {}
    bagOfWordsCount = len(bagOfWords)
    for word, count in wordDict.items():
        tfDict[word] = count / float(bagOfWordsCount)
    return tfDict


def computeIDF(documents):
    import math
    N = len(documents)

    idfDict = dict.fromkeys(documents[0].keys(), 0)
    for document in documents:
        for word, val in document.items():
            if val > 0:
                idfDict[word] += 1

    for word, val in idfDict.items():
        idfDict[word] = math.log(N / float(val))
    return idfDict


def computeTFIDF(tfBagOfWords, idfs):
    tfidf = {}
    for word, val in tfBagOfWords.items():
        tfidf[word] = val * idfs[word]
    return tfidf


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I can compare calculation of Term Frequency. Both results look the same. But when I calculate the IDF and then TF-IDF there are differences between the code from the website and `TfidfVectorizer` (I also try combination of `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfTransformer` to be sure it returns the same results like `TfidfVectorizer` does).

**Code Tf-Idf results:**

[image]

**TfidfVectorizer Tf-Idf results:**

[image]

Can anybody help me with a code that would return the same returns as `TfidfVectorizer` or setting of `TfidfVectorizer` what would return the same results as the code above?

Comment: There are multiple corrections in this. Please refer a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53923657/6347629) for `char`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my improvisation of your code to reproduce `TfidfVectorizer` output for your data .

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from IPython.display import display

documentA = 'the man went out for a walk'
documentB = 'the children sat around the fire'
corpus = [documentA, documentB]
bagOfWordsA = documentA.split(' ')
bagOfWordsB = documentB.split(' ')

uniqueWords = set(bagOfWordsA).union(set(bagOfWordsB))

print('----------- compare word count -------------------')
numOfWordsA = dict.fromkeys(uniqueWords, 0)
for word in bagOfWordsA:
    numOfWordsA[word] += 1
numOfWordsB = dict.fromkeys(uniqueWords, 0)
for word in bagOfWordsB:
    numOfWordsB[word] += 1

series_A = pd.Series(numOfWordsA)
series_B = pd.Series(numOfWordsB)
df = pd.concat([series_A, series_B], axis=1).T
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
display(df)

tf_df = df.divide(df.sum(1),axis='index')

n_d = 1+ tf_df.shape[0]
df_d_t = 1 + (tf_df.values>0).sum(0)
idf = np.log(n_d/df_d_t) + 1

pd.DataFrame(df.values * idf,
                  columns=df.columns )
```

[image]

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w*\\b', norm=None)
pd.DataFrame(tfidf.fit_transform(corpus).todense(),
                  columns=tfidf.get_feature_names() )
```

[image]

More details on the implementation refer the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting).